# Create ImageButton in seperate activity when Save button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I'm trying to do something slightly out of the ordinary. I have an Add a Profile page where a user can add multiple profiles. I want to represent these profiles as circles (ImageButtons) on the homepage.

**Much like this:** [image]

So when a user saves a profile, how could I add one of these circles onto this horizontal scroll view? I would like the created circle to have a letter inside it from the first letter of the created clients name. 
I think this would require me to have all 26 letters of the alphabet already created, but this is no problem.

Any suggestions on how to do this? I'm sorry if I'm not clear, I'd be happy to post any more code or clarify anything. The database I use is Firebase. I'm running the latest version of Android Studio.

Any help is greatly appreciated, cheers guys!

**AddAProfile.java:**

```
public class AddProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etName;
    EditText etCareer;
    CheckBox cbTech;
    CheckBox cbMedi;
    CheckBox nfRenewableEnergy;
    CheckBox nfGoogle;
    CheckBox cfNovartis;
    CheckBox nfTesla;
    CheckBox lrsFB;
    CheckBox lrsAAPL;
    CheckBox lrsYHOO;
    CheckBox cbEURUSD;
    CheckBox lrcuUSDRUB;
    CheckBox lrcoSILVER;
    CheckBox lrcoGOLD;
    CheckBox lrcuGBPUSD;
    CheckBox lriNSDQ;
    CheckBox lriSP500;
    Button bSave;



    DatabaseReference databaseClients;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_profile);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        databaseClients = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("clients");

         etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
         etCareer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCareer);
         cbTech = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbTech);
         cbMedi = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbMedi);
         nfRenewableEnergy = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.nfRenewableEnergy);
        nfGoogle = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.nfGoogle);
        cfNovartis = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cfNovartis);
        nfTesla = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.nfTesla);
        lrsFB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.lrsFB);
        lrsAAPL = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.lrsAAPL);
        lrsYHOO = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.lrsYHOO);
        cbEURUSD = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbEURUSD);
        lrcuUSDRUB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.lrcuUSDRUB);
        lrcoSILVER = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.lrcoSILVER);
        lrcoGOLD = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.lrcoGOLD);
        lrcuGBPUSD = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.lrcuGBPUSD);
        lriNSDQ = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.lriNSDQ);
        lriSP500 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.lriSP500);
        bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);


        ImageButton bSettingsBlack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibSettingsBlack);
        ImageButton bEconCalBlack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibEconCalBlack);
        ImageButton bLiveRates = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibLiveRates);
        ImageButton bNewsBlack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibNewsBlack);

        bSettingsBlack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(AddProfileActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
            }
        });
        bEconCalBlack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(AddProfileActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class));
            }
        });
        bLiveRates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(AddProfileActivity.this, sortingrates.class));
            }
        });
        bNewsBlack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(AddProfileActivity.this, HomePageNews.class));
            }
        });

        bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                bSave();

            }
        });



    }

    private void bSave(){
        String name = etName.getText().toString().trim();
        String career = etCareer.getText().toString().trim();
        Boolean techCB = cbTech.isChecked();
        Boolean mediCB = cbMedi.isChecked();
        Boolean renewableEnergyNF = nfRenewableEnergy.isChecked();
        Boolean googleNF = nfGoogle.isChecked();
        Boolean novartisNF = cfNovartis.isChecked();
        Boolean teslaNF = nfTesla.isChecked();
        Boolean fbLRS = lrsFB.isChecked();
        Boolean applLRS = lrsAAPL.isChecked();
        Boolean yhooLRS = lrsYHOO.isChecked();
        Boolean eurusdCB = cbEURUSD.isChecked();
        Boolean usdrubCU = lrcuUSDRUB.isChecked();
        Boolean silverCO = lrcoSILVER.isChecked();
        Boolean goldCO = lrcoGOLD.isChecked();
        Boolean gbpusdCU = lrcuGBPUSD.isChecked();
        Boolean nsdqI = lriNSDQ.isChecked();
        Boolean sp500I = lriSP500.isChecked();


        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
          String id =  databaseClients.push().getKey();

            Clients clients = new Clients(id, name, career, techCB, mediCB, renewableEnergyNF, googleNF,
                    novartisNF, teslaNF, fbLRS, applLRS, yhooLRS, eurusdCB, usdrubCU, silverCO,
                    goldCO, gbpusdCU, nsdqI, sp500I );

            databaseClients.child(id).setValue(clients);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Client added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            startActivity(new Intent(AddProfileActivity.this, AddProfileActivity.class));



        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    }

}
```

**EDIT (What I've tried):**
I tired with other buttons as an experiment to change the image as I couldn't figure out to straight up create it.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main17);

        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                assert(R.id.imageView3 == imageView.getId());
                Integer integer = (Integer) imageView.getTag();
                integer = integer == null ? 0 : integer;
                switch(integer) {
                    case R.drawable.circlesambergrey2:
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell);
                        imageView.setTag(R.drawable.bell);
                        break;
                    case R.drawable.bell:
                    default:
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.circlesambergrey2);
                        imageView.setTag(R.drawable.circlesambergrey2);
                        break;}
                }
            });
        }
```

I've also thought that the user could select the image button with the correct letter from a spinner. This is what I am currently trying! Cheers.

Comment: a question like this shows that you made no effort to solve the problem

Comment: try to think, use your mind

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafiz I have tried many things but with no resolve, and so it wouldn't be any help to post them, but I can edit the question with past effort if you'd like. I'm just stuck here, cheers.

Comment: alright you should add your efforts

Comment: for a simple answer make a public static method in the other activity

Comment: and call it from this activity

Comment: this is a simple hint

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafiz Edit has been done:) I can add more if you like. OK, will try work from that. Cheers.